# WebServlet is not working on another environment

Tags: rest, servlets, prestashop, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I developed a RestAPI using WebServlet with java JDK version 1.7 and weblogic 11g. Everything is working fine on my local machine. We can access or test the endpoint URL using postman in our local. However, when we deploy it on another environment server (UAT server), I am getting the **HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL**. The UAT server is also using JDK1.7 with weblogic 11g. This is my first time developing a RESTAPI and I don't know what could be the reason why I am getting the error. Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this error?